# Load testing WCF services gives huge (>200 sec) responses

Tags: performance, wcf, iis, soap, scalability

I have a service being load tested by a third party. A few minutes after starting, we start to see requests hanging for a very long period of time and the caller ultimately times out (after 60 seconds).

They are testing with 15 users with each user using two devices at once, so a total of 30 connections.

The service is a simple façade to a more complex operation, calling an external system. Benchmarking our communications to the external system looks as though everything is responding in the time we would expect (sub 200ms).

The IIS logs reveals a bunch of very high requests (> 200sec) which ultimately do return a 200 and have Win32 error code `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETD` (error `64`). I have checked the Service Log and can match up the response to the request (based on the SOAP message id) and can see that we do eventually respond with the correct information (although the client has long given up).

Any ideas as to what could be causing this behavior? We're hosting in IIS using wsHttpBinding and we're using WS-Security with x509 certificates (message & transport encryption).

We don't have benchmark logging inside of our service but the code is a very simple mapping of the WCF request to the server request, making the request, and mapping the response to the WCF response. We do this manually and there is no parsing involved (straight assignments).

Comment: How is service instancing configured? How is concurrency configured?

Comment: Use synchronisation = false, Instance Per Call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a detailed investigation, including getting Microsoft support involved we were hitting up against the serviceThrottling defaults, specifically the `maxConcurrentSessions`. We determined this from `perfmon` - there is a counter for this. We were unsure as to why we saw this as the service behaved when called with a .NET client.

It turns out that the Java consumer of this application, using CXF, was not respecting the WSDL (specifically the bit about WS-SecureConversation) and closing sessions out when it closed its connection.

Our solution was to jack up the `maxConcurrentSessions` to a high number, set the `inactivityTimeout` down low (to a minute) to force session abandonment. In addition, we set `establishSecurityContext` to false to avoid the WSS negotiation consuming an additional session.

The solution is inelegant as the service logs are littered with errors about forced session closures, but it fixed the issue we were seeing here. Unfortunately we had a requirement for WS-Security so our solution needed to stick with that.

I hope this helps someone as this was an interesting and time consuming problem to pin down.

Comment: I had a question on the service log errors and also about mainframe. My profile has a link for Link ed In and I'd love to ask more about them